# Update android app

Tags: android, google-play

I wrote (in Eclipse) and published android application last year. Since this time I started to  use Android Studio. Moreover, I am not sure where is my last version of code.

Can I create new version of application and update old apk on google play?

Comment: Goto your play store account and here you can see your last publish app version code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long you have the same package name and same signature.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use same package name and same signing certificate which was created by your first application export wizard.